# What is meant by 'penetration of atomic orbitals'?

Tags: quantum-chemistry

While studying atomic structure, I have faced this term very often. I assume this is a very detailed type question!
But if anyone can please provide just the preliminary idea about this, it will be helpful.

Comment: Hey there! That's a good question, however, the *answer* to question that user @Pritt linked carries a brief explanation of "penetration of atomic orbitals" and is presumably what you want. So, assuming you require nothing else, we'll be closing this question as a "duplicate" (we do this to reduce clutter on the site). However, if that answer does *not* have what you're looking for, then by all means go ahead and edit your question to include specifics and it (may) be re-opened. We look forward to your future participation on Chemistry.SE. Cheers!